# Getting Object values from React/Flux store

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, store, flux

I have a object in the AppStore and doing console.log shows the values I need are available in there.

In componentDidMount() I have assigned the store to a const:

```
const appStoreState = AppStore.getState()
```

But how do I access the values? I tried:

```
appStoreState.keyName
```

but it returns as undefined. I also tried:

```
appStoreState.get('keyName')
```

based on docs here (https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html) but that errors telling me that get is not a function of the const.

What is the correct syntax to use the value?

Thanks in advance,

Tony.

Comment: `get` isn't a property of the state, so that won't work. If there's a value at `keyName` then this should work--but we have no way to diagnose anything beyond that other than to say maybe there's nothing under that key.

Comment: Have you tried console.log to see appStoreState contents?

Comment: Yeah - with console.log I can see the keys/values on the expected tree. But the two methods fail to see those values on the next line.

console.log('store', appStoreState, appStoreState.keyName);

The appStoreState returns the object just as I expect, but drilling down into it just returns undefined:

store Object {} undefined

Does it make any difference that the objects are nested? i.e the value I want is actually at appStoreState.keyName.keyName2.keyName3?

I can see the full structure is in there - just can't access it :)